# Porting existing c# to java (lots of pinvoke/user32.dll) - Pitfalls?

Tags: c#, java, porting

As states we are in the process of considering porting an existing app which uses the `user32.dll` quite extensively. Mainly for stuff like taking screenshots of the screen and moving the mouse around.

Using something like JNA we should be able to do the same thing, but are there limitations? Things we should be aware of

Thank you

Comment: One of my peeves here is people that downvote new users without leaving a comment to help them improve.

Comment: @Eric J agreed, and as far as I can see it's a perfectly valid (and good) question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a first point I'd have to ask why? If you're using JNA you're losing all the cross platform nature of Java anyway, and losing the tight integration with Windows that C# gives you. There's no limitations that'd stop you doing it, but if you are just tying yourself to using native code anyway then I'd say there's not much point.

If on the other hand you're looking to gain cross platform capability and you're looking at porting, then you can take screenshots and move the mouse around using the Java [Robot](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class easily, no native code required. If you are rewriting in Java, that's by far the approach I'd recommend.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, we are well aware of losing cross platform aspects of java, but that's not an issue. We like the java libraries, the language, the tooling and would prefer to move forward in that.

Comment: @npiv That's fair enough, as long as you're aware of it! I'd still advocate using the Robot class rather than native code where you can though - even if don't care about the cross platform side of things, you'll just have cleaner, easier to understand and more maintainable code that way.